# Pattern for writing synchronous and asynchronous methods in libraries and keeping it DRY

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm modifying a library to add async methods. From [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx) it states I shouldn't just write a wrapper around `Task.Result` when calling the synchronous method. But how do I not have to duplicate a lot of code between async methods and sync methods, as we want to keep both options in the library?

For example the library currently uses `TextReader.Read` method. Part of the asynchronous change we would like to use `TextReader.ReadAsync` method. Since this is at the core of the libraries it would seem I would need to duplicate a lot of code between the synchronous and asynchronous methods (want to keep the code DRY as possible). Or I need to refactor them out in a `PreRead` and `PostRead` methods which seems to clutter the code and what the TPL was trying to fix.

I'm thinking about just wrapping the `TextReader.Read` method in a `Task.Return()`. Even with it being a task the improvements from the TPL should not have it switch to a different thread and I can still use the async await for the most of the code like normal. Would it then be ok to have a wrapper of the synchronous to be just `Task.Result` or `Wait()`?

I looked at other examples in the .net library. The `StreamReader` seems to duplicate the code between the async and non async. The `MemoryStream` does a `Task.FromResult`.

Also planning everywhere I could adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` as it's just a library.

**Update:**

What I'm talking about duplicated code is

```
 public decimal ReadDecimal()
 {
     do
     {
          if (!Read())
          {
               SetInternalProperies()
          }
          else
          {
               return _reader.AsDecimal();
          }
      } while (_reader.hasValue)
 }

 public async Task<decimal> ReadDecimalAsync()
 {
     do
     {
          if (!await ReadAsync())
          {
               SetInternalProperies()
          }
          else
          {
               return _reader.AsDecimal();
          }
      } while (_reader.hasValue)
  }
```

This is a small example but you can see the only code change is the awaiting and task.

To make it clear I want to code using async/await and TPL everywhere in the library but I still need to also have the old sync methods work as well. I'm not about to just `Task.FromResult()` the sync methods. What I was thinking was having a flag that says I want the sync method and at the root check the flag something like

```
 public decimal ReadDecimal()
 { 
     return ReadDecimalAsyncInternal(true).Result;
 }

 public async Task<decimal> ReadDecimal()
 {
     return await ReadDecimalAsyncInternal(false);
 }

 private async Task<decimal> ReadDecimalAsyncInternal(bool syncRequest)
 {
     do
     {
          if (!await ReadAsync(syncRequest))
          {
               SetInternalProperies()
          }
          else
          {
               return _reader.AsDecimal();
          }
      } while (_reader.hasValue)
}

private Task<bool> ReadAsync(bool syncRequest)
{
    if(syncRequest)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(streamReader.Read())
    }
    else
    {
        return StreamReader.ReadAsync(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to expose synchronous and asynchronous version of method? An operation can either be synchronous or asynchronous. It can't be both. Choose the right thing, not both. Then with the client code, you can call it eitherway.

Comment: It's a library.  We have existing code that uses it and we don't want to have to change all that.  It's the same thing as TextReader.Read and TextReader.ReadAsync we are adding the "async" method to the library like Library.Method and Library.MethodAsync

Comment: A Task.Result wrapper gives you nothing positive. await will simply synchronously get the value stored in that task. The method signature is misleading. Only expose async methods that are actually async internally.

Comment: @Sriram - Why do you assume an operation may be only one or the other? WinAPI exposes both synchronous and asynchronous reads from disk. How does that fall into your assumption?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov reading disk is naturally asynchronous, it doesn't need any thread to read the file. The fact that windows provide synchronous API is that file data could be in file system cache if it has read recently, in that case the operation will complete synchronously. Otherwise it is asynchronous, windows just lock up your thread to make you feel it is synchronous, but really not.

Comment: You're right. It naturally async. But you still *can* use both versions. I see no reason to make that choice.

Answer (score 7):

You want to add async methods in addition to the synchronous ones in your lib. The article you linked to talks exactly about that. It recommend to create specialized code for both versions.

Now that advice is usually given because:

1. Async methods should be low-latency. For efficiency they should use async IO internally.
2. Sync methods should use sync IO internally for efficiency reasons.

If you create wrappers you might mislead callers.

Now, it is a **valid** strategy to create wrappers both ways if you are OK with the consequences. It certainly saves a lot of code. But you will have to decide whether to give preference to the sync or to the async version. The other one will be less efficient and have no performance-based reason to exist.

You will rarely find this in the BCL because the quality of implementation is high. But for example ADO.NET 4.5's `SqlConnection` class uses sync-over-async. The cost of doing a SQL call is far greater than the sync overhead. That's an OK use case. `MemoryStream` uses (kind of) async-over-sync because it is inherently CPU-only work but it must implement `Stream`.

What's the overhead actually? Expect to be able to run >100 million `Task.FromResult` per second and millions of almost zero work `Task.Run` per second. That's small overhead compared to many things.

---

**Please see the comments below for an interesting discussion.** To preserve that content I am copying some comments into this answer. In copying I tried to leave out subjective remarks as much as possible since this answer is meant to be objectively true. The full discussion is below.

It is possible to reliably avoid deadlocks. For example, ADO.NET uses sync-over-async in recent versions. You can see this when pausing the debugger while queries are running and looking at the call stack. It is common wisdom that sync-over-async is problematic and it's true. But it is false that you categorically cannot use it. It is a trade-off.

The following pattern is always safe (just an example): `Task.Run(() => Async()).Wait();`. This is safe because Async is called without synchronization context. The deadlock potential normally comes from an async method capturing the sync context, which is single threaded, and then wanting to re-enter it. An alternative is to consistently use `ConfigureAwait(false)` which is error prone (one error deadlocks your production app at 4:00 in the morning). Another alternative is `SetSyncContext(null); var task = Async(); SetSyncContext(previous);`.

I also like the idea with the boolean flag. It is another possible trade-off. Most application do not care about optimizing performance in these small ways. They want correctness and developer productivity. Async is bad for both in many cases.

If you want an async method to be callable in an arbitrary way than it must use `ConfigureAwait(false)` which is recommended for library code anyway. Then, you can just use `Wait()` without danger. I also want to point out that async IO does not change the speed of the actual work (DB, web service) in any way. It also adds CPU call overhead (more, not less overhead). Any perf gains can only come from increasing parallelism. Sync code can do parallelism also. Async is only superior if the parallelism is so high that threading cannot reasonably be used (hundreds).

There are some additional ways that async can increase performance but those are quite minor and occur specialized circumstances. In general, you will find normal synchronous calls to be faster. I know that because I tried it and also from theoretical observations.

Saving threads is pointless when there is not a shortage of threads. Most (not all) server apps are not short on threads in any way. A thread is just 1MB of memory and 1ms of CPU overhead. Usually there are ample threads available to handle incoming requests and other work. We have programmed our applications with sync IO for the last 20 years and it was totally fine.

I want to clarify that sync over async usually has more overhead because it combines the overhead from async with the overhead of waiting on a Task. A purely synchronous call chain uses less CPU than a purely async call chain in almost all cases, though. But then again these little performance differences do not matter in almost all cases. So we should optimize for developer productivity.

Great cases for async are IOs which are long running and frequent. Also, large degrees of parallelism (for example, if you want to connect to 1 million chat clients over TCP, or you are querying a web service with 100 parallel connections). Here, async IO has meaningful performance and reliability gains. Task + await is an awesome way to implement this. await plus async IO also is very nice in client GUI apps. I do not want to create the impression that I'm against async categorically.

But you can also flexibly transition out of async. E.g. `Task.WaitAll(arrayWith100IOTasks)` would burn just one thread waiting for 100 parallel IOs. That way you avoid infecting the entire call stack and you save 99 threads. In GUI apps you can often do `await Task.Run(() => LotsOfCodeUsingSyncIO())`. Again, just one place infected with async and you have nice code.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect, sorry! What the OP says they are going to do (see their comment on @YuvalItzchakov's answer) is to put sync wrappers round their new async code. The trouble with this - and it is the main topic of the article which the OP links to - is that is can cause the application to hang. Deadlock. NOT just to be inefficient! So whilst I would agree with the OP it would be lovely not to have to duplicate so much code, putting sync wrappers round async is not a valid strategy to avoid this (at least, not as I have understood things). Sorry, and thanks!

Comment: @MikeBeaton I understand that he wants sync-over-async. It is possible to reliably avoid deadlocks. For example, ADO.NET uses sync-over-async in recent versions. You can see this when pausing the debugger while queries are running and looking at the call stack. It is common wisdom that sync-over-async is problematic and it's true. But it is false that you categorically cannot use it. It is a trade-off.

Comment: I've come across a way to do sync over async safely, using a behind-the-scenes 'aync' method which has a sync and an async path, selected on a boolean flag. (I don't know if that's what ADO.NET uses - one could check.) Your answer sounds well informed and plausible, and in fact as far as I can see you're *right* about the efficiency issues which you discuss. But efficiency isn't the serious problem here. I currently still don't believe it is possible to avoid hangs with a sync wrapper over a genuinely async path through an async method.

Comment: @MikeBeaton the following pattern is always safe (just an example): `Task.Run(() => Async()).Wait();`. This is safe because `Async` is called without synchronization context. The deadlock potential normally comes from an async method capturing the sync context, which is single threaded, and then wanting to re-enter it. An alternative is to consistently use `ConfigureAwait(false)` which is error prone (one error deadlocks your production app at 4:00 in the morning). Another alternative is `SetSyncContext(null); var task = Async(); SetSyncContext(previous);`.

Comment: @MikeBeaton I also like the idea with the boolean flag. It is another possible trade-off. Most application do not care about optimizing performance in these small ways. They want correctness and developer productivity. Async is bad for both in many cases... Unfortunately, the whole community moves in that direction in a fairly mindless way ("go always async!" - wrong!). Very unfortunate.

Comment: I think it would be important to remember that an async method cannot really be considered safe if it has to be called in a certain non-standard way to be safe - certainly not for anybody writing library code. You still mention performance trade-offs but the main issue of wrapping sync-async or async-sync is NOT perfomance, but safety (no hangs). Yes, the main reason to use async at all is performance, and scalability, but using async for real async tasks (waiting on an external DB, for instance) can be MUCH higher in performance and scalability than using sync.

Comment: @MikeBeaton you raise a good point with safety. If you want an async method to be callable in an arbitrary way than it must use CF(false) which is recommended for library code anyway. Then, you can just use Wait() without danger. I also want to point out that async IO does not change the speed of the actual work (DB, web service) in any way. It also adds CPU call overhead (more, not less overhead). Any perf gains can only come from increasing parallelism. Sync code can do parallelism also. Async is only superior if the parallelism is so high that threading cannot reasonably be used (hundreds).

Comment: There are some additional ways that async can increase performance but those are quite minor and occur specialized circumstances. In general, you will find normal synchronous calls to be faster. I know that because I tried it and also from theoretical observations. The idea that async is faster is part of the mass delusion that currently exists around async... I'm only half joking.

Comment: You may be half joking, but you are also wrong and your answer is misleading. The theoretical issue is not complex. IF there is something happening which involves a thread simply waiting for an external database to respond, THEN there will be more threads free to respond if that thread is freed-up (say, to serve other API calls on a webserver). Even more definitely (if possible), if a JavaScript application waits for an API call to complete then the browser simply hangs. You are SIMPLY WRONG that the main issue here is a minor efficiency increase, which only occurs in arcane circumstances.

Comment: @MikeBeaton I'm happy to discuss this if you are. Saving threads is pointless when there is not a shortage of threads. Most (not all) server apps are not short on threads in any way. A thread is just 1MB of memory and 1ms of CPU overhead. Usually there are ample threads available to handle incoming requests and other work. We have programmed our applications with sync IO for the last 20 years and it was totally fine... JavaScript is an entirely different matter because there you're forced to go all async. .NET is not constrained like that.

Comment: And it really is a constraint that JavaScript has. It's not a good thing. The Node.js community likes to spin this in a positive way. They say: Look with our async IO we have all this scalability! But really, you can just do less with JavaScript than with .NET because you're forced into this model when you don't need it. With .NET on the server you can mix sync and async in the same app. Get the productivity of sync for 99% of code and use async in those places that really benefit (e.g. long running calls in a high frequency code path). This again is heresy but true and I'm happy to explain.

Comment: Can I backtrack a bit? Your points seem interesting, and having now played with implementing async in quite a large library ... it does seem surprisingly slow! Can I rephrase my point? There are widely-quoted web articles saying that sync over async is bad because it will cause hangs, in unpredictable ways. The view that it is safe, and the research you've done to show that it's not only safe but faster, are very much not well known. And most of that interesting info only exists in your comments here, not in your answer itself! Do you have any other references, blog posts, etc, at all?!

Comment: @MikeBeaton There is not much content about this on the web. There is some but I don't have it at hand and it's hard to find. We are in full on hype mode around async. Group think has taken over and is currently dominating common wisdom. This is a normal process. In our industry it happens every few years around some new topic. Form your own thoughts and grow as a professional that way. If something you read does not make sense - it likely doesn't.

Comment: But I want to clarify that sync over async usually has more overhead because it combines the overhead from async with the overhead of waiting on a Task. A purely synchronous call chain uses less CPU than a purely async call chain in almost all cases, though. But then again these little performance differences do not matter in almost all cases. So we should optimize for developer productivity.

Comment: Great cases for async are IOs which are long running and frequent. Also, large degrees of parallelism (for example, if you want to connect to 1 million chat clients over TCP, or you are querying a web service with 100 parallel connections). Here, async IO has meaningful performance and reliability gains. `Task` + `await` is an awesome way to implement this. `await` plus async IO also is very nice in client GUI apps. I do not want to create the impression that I'm against async categorically.

Comment: But you can also flexibly transition out of async. E.g. `Task.WaitAll(arrayWith100IOTasks)` would burn just one thread waiting for 100 parallel IOs. That way you avoid infecting the entire call stack and you save 99 threads. In GUI apps you can often do `await Task.Run(() => LotsOfCodeUsingSyncIO())`. Again, just one place infected with async and you have nice code.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it then be ok to have a wrapper of the synchronous to be just Task.Result or Wait()?

You have to understand what async IO is all about. Its not about code duplication, its about taking advantage of the fact that you don't need any threads when the work is naturally asynchronous.

If you'd wrap your synchronous code with a task, you're missing out on that advantage. Also, you'd be misleading your API callers when they'd assume the awaited call would yield control back to the caller.

**Edit:**

Your examples strengthens my point. Don't from the use of tasks. Synchronous apis by themselves are completely fine, dont force the use of TPL into them when it isn't needed, eveb if it causes your codebase to grow 2x the amount of lines.

Take the time to implement your async api correctly. Don't block on async code, keep it flowing all the way to the bottom of the stack.

Comment: I want to do the opposite.  I want to write using the TPL async await code but can't break the existing library that is currently written using sync code.  The example is I want to use TextReader.ReadAsync where we currently have TextReader.Read.  I'll make all the method calls have the Task<> await calls.  But I still need to support the old sync methods and that I wanted to use the Async code and just block on Result or Wait(). But that seems frowned at.

Comment: @CharlesNRice you want to add async methods in addition to the synchronous ones in your lib, right? The article you linked to talks exactly about that. Don't add async over sync wrappers or the other way around. Why doesn't the article answer your question?

Comment: Don't block on the results. Thats a source for many mistakes and deadlocks. Jeep the synchronous version synchronous, and write the async API using *async all the way*,from top to bottom.

Comment: I've updated my question with example.

Comment: @usr If I need both then I have a lot of duplicated code and duplicated logic.  I've added an update to show that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I guess I'm just having a hard time not seeing this as a violation of DRY and having to maintain two sets of logic that are almost the same and if I have a bug in one I'll probably have it in the other.  Plus it just adds to the maintenance cost.

Comment: @CharlesNRice Even async calls have some parts which are synchronous. If that concerns you, you can always refactor to have that common logic which will be used on both ends. Just try to keep the parts which are purely async encapsulated in the async endpoint. Don't attempt to use them with a `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result`. I've answered far too many questions where people mix it up and end up deadlocking themselves.